# Cut recorded video in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, video, ios7, video-processing

How can i cut the video in objective c.

I am recording the video with 30 seconds.
Wants to cut 10 second video in 30 seconds.

I referred this - [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage),[Play Record Edit Video](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)

Anyone please suggest me which is the best way to do this.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at "Trimming and Transcoding a Movie", in the AV Foundation Programming Guide here.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html

Comment: Perfect exactly same i was looking for. Thank you.